# Javascript not adding questions or buttons to webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a quiz website and I used some simple interactive quiz code and the next button is there (only button I have that doesn't have display set to none). The Javascript was supposed to show the first question upon opening the page, and then showing the next one each time you hit next. After the first question the previous button should show up and at the end it would give you your score and the start over button. 
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>History</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css.css">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='javascript.js'></script>
    </head>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="headnav">
            <h1 class="navitem">World Wide Water</h1> <!-- Going to be the header with navigatioon bar-->
            <ul id="nav">
                <a href="../frontpage.html"><li class="navitem">Home</li></a>
                <a href="about.html"><li class="navitem">About</li></a>
                <a href="../subjects.html"><li class="navitem">Subjects</li></a>
                <a href="share.html"><li class="navitem">Share</li></a>
                <a href="donate.html"><li class="navitem">Donate More!</li></a>
            </ul>
            <div id="header">
                <div id="headerbar">
                    <div id="logo"></div>
                    <div id="site-sloagan"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mainhis">
        <p>If i do this will it work</p>
            <div id="quiz"></div>
            <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Previous</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='start'><a href='#'>Start Over</a></div>         
        </div>
</div></html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("bg.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#headnav {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 153);
    color: white;
    }
#main {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 900px;

}
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: center;

}
.navitem {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
}
.linkonsub {
    color: black;
}
#id {
    text-align: left;
}
#sub {
    background-color: rgb(211, 112, 40);
    text-align: left;
}
#mainhis {
     width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0 25px 40px 10px;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    border:4px solid #B0E0E6;
    border-radius:5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 
    #888;
}
#quiz {
    text-indent: 10px;
    display:none;
}
.button {
    border:4px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    width: 40px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    color: black;
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
.button.active {
    background-color: #F8F8FF
    color: #525252;
}
button {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#prev {
    display: none;
}
#start {
    display: none;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "What is 2*5?",
    choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }, {
    question: "What is 3*6?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*9?",
    choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is 1*7?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*8?",
    choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }];

  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      alert('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
  });

  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });

  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
  });

  // Animates buttons on hover
  $('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  $('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);

    return qElement;
  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if(questionCounter < questions.length){
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if(questionCounter === 1){
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if(questionCounter === 0){

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      }else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }

    score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' right!!!');
    return score;
  }
})();
```

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/edg5rqfo/ How is it not working for you? What's actually happening?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers Javascript isn't inputting any questions and all that is showing up is a tiny blue box. http://imgur.com/a/nuc6n <-What I see

Comment: @Clonkex http://imgur.com/a/nuc6n This is all that shows up for me

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: From the above snippet it seems like you included css file which is outside the current folder where your html and js file is. Alos your JS file was included twice.

Comment: Managed to replicate the issue, trying to solve now.

Comment: @Clonkext Not sure why I didn't check this earlier: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.  history.html  Am a new webdev and not sure what to do from here. Thank you for the help, am currently trying to reformat stuff so it's in the same folder like visrey said

Comment: @visrey I will try restructuring things now

Comment: Worked it out and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is very simple. You're missing the `$` at the very start of the Javascript code. Add that in and you're golden. To explain, you can use the dollar sign as a function name. jQuery (which you're using) does this to make it very quick and easy to type. When you use `$` all by itself, it takes a function as an argument (i.e. you pass in a callback function) and that callback function is called as soon as the page is loaded. That's nothing special or magical, it's just what the `$()` function does, and it's part of jQuery. People use it because the callback function is called when the page is ready to be manipulated; that is, it's called when all the HTML has been generated, which means it's safe for the Javascript to start messing around with it.

So your code was just running before the page was ready.

Fix like so:

```
$(function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "What is 2*5?",
    choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }, {
    question: "What is 3*6?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*9?",
    choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is 1*7?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*8?",
    choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }];

  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      alert('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
  });

  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });

  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
  });

  // Animates buttons on hover
  $('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  $('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);

    return qElement;
  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if(questionCounter < questions.length){
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if(questionCounter === 1){
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if(questionCounter === 0){

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      }else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }

    score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' right!!!');
    return score;
  }
})();
```

Of course your head should also look more like this:

```
    <head>
        <title>History</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='javascript.js'></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works perfectly now. And I updated the head :P

Comment: @MattRodosky Nice haha, glad I could help! Often the tiniest bugs are the hardest to solve, and this one had me scratching my head for quite a while :P

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have two problems here and both are related to html and js loading.

1. you are linking your script twice (maybe copy error?) and the first time before you add reference to jQuery, so your script is failing because it is loaded before you add jQuery and since your script is self executing function it will try to run immediately after it is loaded but will fail because jQuery which it relies on is not loaded yet.
2. again your script will run as soon as it is loaded and not add the correct handlers, etc.. because it is actually loaded before the rest of the html code, so it can't add those handlers to elements. So your solution here is either use some body onload hook and do the init there, or put the `<script type="text/javascript" src='javascript.js'></script>`at the bottom of the page so when it is loaded you can be sure that rest of the HTML code is loaded as well.

Comment: Neither of those are the issue. In testing I've found loading the script once doesn't fix it, and he's using jQuery's ready function so it doesn't matter where the script goes.

Comment: Just tried moving it to no avail. Thanks for the help @Clonkex

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your function "(function() {" with 
"$(window).on("load", function() {"
Your Quiz div is getting loaded later on after the functions get executed and hence your first question is not getting loaded. Hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: I fixed by simply putting a $ before "(function()" as Clonkex suggested and it worked. I don't think the order matters because of Jquery's ready function.